# Dealing with Datagrids in WPF Application

Tags: .net, xml, wpf, drop-down-menu, datagrid

I Really need help in this ...

I'm building an application where I need to have somethings in the datagrid.

I want to have the datagrid to have drop-down lists, these lists will will change depending on other drop-down values, also depending on previous values. I can handle this ...

I want to know how to know how to create the datagrid, i.e. how to add columns (statically), rows (dynamically).

Mainly, the data will be stored in XML file.

Comment: Question is not very clear.  This is link of a combobox in a DataGrid.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639264/using-a-databound-combobox-on-a-datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
//Load XML file and set the DataGrid data context
XElement mymusic = XElement.Load("mymusic.xml");
dg1.DataContext = mymusic.Elements("Album");
```

Xaml:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Album Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Title].Value}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" />
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist" Binding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Artist].Value}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}"/>
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Release Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Attribute[ReleaseDate].Value}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" />
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Check this article for more details -

[A DataGrid sample using XML data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/11/25/a-datagrid-sample-using-xml-data.aspx)

Comment: Ok, this is just a part of what I need .. some of the elements in the XML will be referring to a value of a drop-down menu ... How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use the attribute as in other columns; another approach - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Ashish1/PopulateDropDownInsideDatagrid11292005234748PM/PopulateDropDownInsideDatagrid.aspx